# Union spark Datasets in loop

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to append a dataset to an empty dataset in a loop.
But the resultant dataset is always empty.

I tried to eliminate the variable `failedRows` from the loop by executing just Line 1 commented in code but still got empty `failedRows` dataset.

```
Dataset<Row> failedRows = sparkSession.createDataFrame(new ArrayList<>(), itemsDS.schema());
failedRows.count();
Dataset<Row> filteredDs;
for(String tagName: mandatoryTagsList){
    //failedRows.union(itemsDS.filter(functions.col(tagName).isNull()));//Line 1
    filteredDs = itemsDS.filter(functions.col(tagName).isNull());
    if(filteredDs.count()>0){
        failedRows.union(filteredDs);//Line 2
        failedRows.count();
    }
}
```

Does anybody know why exactly the union is not generating the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save to a new variable each time.

`Dataset` same as all distributed collections in Spark are immutable.

```
failedRows = failedRows.union(filteredDs);//Line 2
```